# Type convertion in Impala table with parquet files

Tags: hadoop, parquet, impala

I am having trouble changing the type of a column from `string` to `int` with Impala using parquet files.

Using:

`alter table DATABASE.TABLE change COL COL Int` (from string to int)

or

`alter table DATABASE.TABLE change COL COL string` (from int to string)

Produces an error when reading the data:

> file x has an incompatible Parquet schema for column 'db.table.col'.
> Column type: INT, Parquet schema: optional byte_array col [i:1 d:1
> r:0]

Reading [this](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_parquet.html) documentation, I understand that:

- TINYINT to SMALLINT/INT : ok
- SMALLINT to INT: ok

Considering the following:

> Any other type conversion for columns produces a conversion error
> during queries

Does that mean ALL type conversion, except those above, are possible (query goes through) but will raise an error when querying ?

Additionnal information:

- A refresh table before the compute stats (or select) does not fix the issue.
- Same for invalidate metadata after changing column type.
- The problem appears both in Hue or when using python script.
- I am using impalad version 2.12.0-cdh5.16.2 RELEASE
- The error concerns the first parquet file (the one with the content of the table before updating the type).
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are changing data type( metadata), you need to `invalidate metadata` so that impala forced to look for metadata and not use old metadata.

So, after  your alter statement pls use this to fix the error. Impala will use latest metadata while querying and SQL will work fine.

```
INVALIDATE METADATA mytable
```

Comment: Unfortunately, after an invalidation, the error persists.

Comment: i was able to recreate your issue in my system and it was resolved by doing invalidate. Can you try `refresh mytable` ? I am not sure why its not working in your system. Are you using hue or some other tool? What is your cloudera impala version?

Comment: A refresh table before the compute stats (or select) does not fix the issue. Same for invalidate metadata after changing column type. The problem appears both in Hue or when using python script. I am using impalad version 2.12.0-cdh5.16.2 RELEASE

Comment: i am not talking about compute stats because its irrelevant when you change table structure.